# Sencha Ajax call not working

Tags: ajax, extjs, cordova, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I’m trying to access a web service with Sencha touch. With an JSONP call from the browser, all works fine. When we switch the application to a physical device, and change the JSONP request (no longer needed on an real device) to an ordinary AJAX call, nothing happens.....

What is the right way, to fix this? We're using PHONEGAP, I think something probably is wrong with the container, because the call itself looks like it should (-> And is working in the browser, where PHONEGAP is not needed and therefore not included.)

Here is my code:

1. Ajax-Call for the Mobile (not working)

   `// 1. When we use this on the DEVICE, it DOESEN'T work. 
   // It seems, like the call isnt fired at all
   // JSONP we don't need here......
   alert("Ajax request is send");
   Ext.Ajax.request ({
       url: Adress_To_Webserver,
       method: 'GET',
       timeout: 1000,
       success: function(response, opts) {
           alert("sucess");
           //alert(Ext.decode(response.responseText));
           //var obj = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
           console.dir(obj);
       },
       failure: function(response, opts) {
           alert("error");
       }
   });`
2. JSONP-Call for the Browser (working)

   `// 2. If we do the same Call (JSONP) on the BROWSER, it WORKS.
   alert("Ajax request is send");
   Ext.data.JsonP.request ({
   url: Adress_To_Webserver,
   timeout: 1000,
   callbackKey: "myjson",
   params: {
        callback: function (jsonData) {
   }},
   success: function(response, opts) {
         alert("sucess");
         alert(Ext.decode(response.responseText));
         var obj = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
         console.dir(obj);
    },
    failure: function(response, opts) {
         alert("error");
    }
    });`

It would be great, if someone have a hint/solution for this problem - like i mentioned, i'm using sencha architect to build a android app. The Phonegap folder with the .apk is created automaticaly, all permissions in the config.xml are set. Phonegap plugins have been also installed. Probably, some more dependencies are missing or wrong - what will be a good place for looking?

Thanks in advance for helping,
Daniel

Comment: Why is the JSONP request no longer needed?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you don't set up the `<access>` property in the config.xml file to `origin="*"` or whatever domain you need. This property specifies all exteranal domains which phonegap allows your web app to access.

So, your config.xml file should contain the following line:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

Instead of '*' your can put your resource from which you retrieve you data.

There is the explicit description how to use it [white list (phonegap)](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Whitelist%20Guide)

Comment: Thanks for answering. That was the first step I did, but unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem. I will try a few things today, if I get a solution, i'll post it here.....